# Disable Template Cache Jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to disable Jinja2's template cache. I've done some looking around, and I've found that there's a `cache_size` parameter for jinja's environment. I'm using the following:

```
app.jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(
    cache_size = 0, 
    loader = jinja2.FunctionLoader(utils.load_template)
)
```

I'm using a custom loader to dynamically load templates based on the domain (the app serves multiple domains). Unfortunately, using this, it looks like it overrides Jinja's default filters and builtin functions - using

```
@app.route(...)
def page():
    render_template('template') # from flask import render_template
```

I'm getting a `UndefinedError: 'url_for' is undefined` error. What's the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You might want to set `app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True` instead. Instead of disabling the cache, it will reload templates if the cached version no longer matches the template file.

Answer (score 0):

If using FastAPI:

```
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory='templates', auto_reload=True)
```