# How to run Flask without caching templates?

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

I have a `Flask` app running with `python-socketio` and `eventlet`.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import eventlet
    import eventlet.wsgi
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 5000)), app)
```

Every time I change anything in the templates it does not affect the app and I have to restart the app (`CTRL+C` and then again `python app.py`). How can I disable this "cache" or rather enable template reloading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable the debug mode in your app config: `app.debug = True` or `app.config['DEBUG'] = True`. Just make sure you enable this flag only in development since it can have performance and security implications. You can find more details in [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/).

Comment: When I see that now it seems so obvious :) Thanks!

Comment: @JanuszKamieński Proszę bardzo :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case `app.debug = True` did not work, but `app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True` did, per [Disable Template Cache Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575089/disable-template-cache-jinja2).